# Setting up a functional Node/Angular/Postgres project on AWS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services

First, please forgive my naive or ignorant sounding questions. The truth is that, while I spent plenty of time coding other people's projects, I have never done any configuration like this before.

A partner and I are building a Postgres/Node/Angular (Although I realize that Mongo is the natural choice he is much more comfortable in Postgres and we decided to use that to make sure that we get the DB right) on AWS (Amazon Web Services). At this point this is what we have:

1) An AWS instance with Node and Postgres installed.
2) An Angular application that is ~25% complete.

At this point the Angular app is not calling server code, instead we have hardcoded in JSON to simulate the server responses. The plan is to write a Node API that is totally decoupled from the Angular front-end.

It is time to merge it all together and we have run into some issues involving the configuration:

1)  What tool can we use to debug the Node code  (until now we have been using the chrome developer to debug the angular JS)?
2)  How do we set up the project to allow for version control of all the code (are there any standard tools)?
3)  If a developer has checked out a version and is working it on his local machine, how can he access the database (we have no firewall and until now we were only planning on opening up the secure ports 443, 115, 22 etc.)? I mean, how can the server code that is running on his machine get access to data?

The point is that I am looking for advice regarding a standard functional set up. I have never set up a project like this and I am kind of lost on where to begin.

Thanks in advance